# My findViewById isn't working on 'MainActivity extends FragmentActivity'

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception, fragment, findviewbyid

My intention is to realize a refresh when I swipe vertically.
The main is extending a FragmentActivty:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

And i`m creating a CustomViewPager too, inside the oncreate:

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeToRefresh;    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            context = this.getApplicationContext();     
            pager = new CustomViewPager(this, null);
            pager.setId(R.id.pager);
            pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
            setContentView(pager);
```

This *pager* is an exemple that i found on internet.

The thing is, as you can see, i`m declaring a SwipeRefreshLayout and i can't call the findViewById without get a null from it. I already checked my xml, there is no compilation error, only nullpointerException on running.

```
swipeToRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
```

I saw few topics about it and they get very close from what I tought, but still it didn't work.
This is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, I have two questions:

1. I need to setContentView of this xml?
2. Why I am getting nullPointer?

Any question just ask, I am available.
Thanks.

Comment: (1) Yes, (2) Because of (1)

Comment: In the onCreate you seem to `setContentView(pager)` which means that your activity is going to show only the `pager`. If you want the layout in the xml to be displayed then you need to `setContentView(R.layout.whatever_your_layout_is)`. And Marcus has already answered the questions that you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have NullPointerException cause you didn't set the content view for the layout file that contains your activity.

You should `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`  (or whatever layout file name you have)right after the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

so this piece of code

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeToRefresh;    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            context = this.getApplicationContext();     
            pager = new CustomViewPager(this, null);
            pager.setId(R.id.pager);
            pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
            setContentView(pager);
```

should look something like this:

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeToRefresh;    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

                context = this.getApplicationContext();     
                pager = new CustomViewPager(this, null);
                pager.setId(R.id.pager)
                pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks guys and Ivan, this is it. At first I thought that the 'pager' was the layout that i wanted, but no, now is clear.